# Why List<? super Number> is OK for Integer and Long type?

Tags: java, generics, java-11

When I was working on lower-upper bound of generics, I came across to [this blog post](https://tudip.com/blog-post/java-generics-lower-upper-bound/#:%7E:text=Upper%2Dbound%20is%20when%20you,Field%20or%20superclass%20of%20Field.).
In the definition if a generics is defined with <? extends ClassA> it is availble for classes that are ClassA or subclass of ClassA.

On the other hand is a generics is defined with <? super ClassA> it is availble for classes that are ClassA or superclass of ClassA.

But when coding in Java11 it seems the opposite
For example:

```
public List getListA() {
   // I think it's valid because Integer extends Number class, but it gives compilation error
   List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(1);
   list.add(1L);
   return list;
}


public List getListB() {
    // I think it's not valid since Integer and Long are not superclass of Number, but it works OK!
    List<? super Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(10);
    list.add(10L);
    return list;
}
```

So can anybody tell me what am I missing here?

Best regards,

Comment: "In the definition" where did you find your definition? `List<? extends Number>`  means "a `List` whose contents are all some subclass of `Number`, but you don't know which": it's a *producer* of `Number` instances, so you don't need to care which subclass that is. `List<? super Number>` means "a `List` to which it is OK to add instances of `Number`: it's a *consumer* of `Number` instances, so you don't need to care if there is anything that's not a `Number` in the list as well, it's merely saying that a subclass of `Number` is an acceptable element.

Comment: @AndyTurner Added the blog post I read to the quesiton

Comment: A `List<? extends Number>` can be a `List<Number>` or a `List<Integer>` or a `List<Long>` (amongst others). If it's a `List<Number>`, it's fine to add either an `Integer` or a `Long` to it; if it's a `List<Integer>`, you don't want to be able to add a `Long` to it; if it's a `List<Long>`, you don't want to be able to add an `Integer` to it. But since you don't know which of those the `List<? extends Number>` is, you're not allowed to add anything to it.